# No picture with a Microsoft VX-1000 webcam in Skype

Tags: skype, webcam, microsoft

I have a problem with my webcam in Skype on Ubuntu 11.10. There is no picture. Yesterday I installed the x64 version and there was a picture, but with strong artifacts. Today I installed the 32-bit version and now there is no picture at all! I tried to configure my webcam in the Video4linux control panel, but when I click Preview there is an error: "Failed to start preview process". Can anybody help me with this? I'm in despair.

The webcam is a Microsoft vx-1000.

Answer (score 1):

Skype has a compatibility problem with the Video4Linux2-Library. You can force it to use the Version 1 of this library then it should work. Shutdown all skype instances and then try running this in a terminal:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype &
```

If you have **64 bit** Linux, use the following command instaed:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype &
```

Comment: please mark his as the answer if it helped Mad_Bear

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype &` on Ubuntu 11.10